# How to make a color histogram based classifier using OpenCV 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, svm, opencv3.0

I am trying to make a classifier using OpenCV 3.0.0's CvSVM and color histogram. I already tried to make my own using the following code to make the datasets:

```
    int labels[510];
    if (label.compare("raw")){
        for (int i = 0; i < 509; i++){
            labels[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (label.compare("ripe")){
        for (int i = 0; i < 509; i++){
            labels[i] = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (label.compare("rotten")){
        for (int i = 0; i < 509; i++){
            labels[i] = 3;
        }
    }
    float trainingData[510][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++){
        trainingData[i][1] = r_hist.at<float>(i - 1);
        trainingData[i][2] = i;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 255; i < 509; i++){
        trainingData[i][1] = g_hist.at<float>(j - 1);
        trainingData[i][2] = i;
        j++;
    }
```

And this code for the SVM:

```
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
    Mat labelsMat(510, 1, CV_32SC1, labels);
    Mat trainingDataMat(510, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

    Ptr < cv::ml::SVM > svm = SVM::create();

    svm = cv::Algorithm::load<ml::SVM>("svm.xml");
    svm->setC(0.01);
    svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::LINEAR);
    svm->setTermCriteria((cvTermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e6)));

    svm->train(trainingDataMat, ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
    svm->save("svm.xml");
```

The problem with the code above is that it won't save properly. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what does "it won't save properly" mean? Is no file generated? Are wrong results saved?

Comment: @Micka The XML file does only contained one support vector and one decision function instead of 510.